# Trying to find a sci-fi novel I read when I was a teenager (early 2000s)

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

First of all the book looked fairly new so I don't think it was more than a few years old at the time and I'm 80% certain I picked it up in the young adult section at my public library.
The story featured a boy whose parents were killed by space pirates and he was kidnapped by the pirate, who was pretty nasty, he eventually escaped and was taken to a planet of aliens that are at war with humans.
They train him to be a spy and, I think, a hacker. I think I remember some sort of contact lens type device he uses to access computer terminals. 
I remember that he is a bit conflicted on whether he should help the aliens, who rescued him, or defect to the humans.

I don't remember how the book ends and believe me I know how vague this is...but I figured I might as well give it a shot. I would really like to re-read and finally finish the book.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's actually not vague at all. I wish all "identify this" posts had as much info. Hopefully someone will recognize it.

Comment: I'm positive that I've seen this book discussed before here: http://www.reddit.com/r/printsf. You might post this same question there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Warchild by Karin Lowachee

When Jos' parents are killed in an attack on their trading ship, the boy is kidnapped by his attackers and then escapes - only to fall into the alien hands of humanity's greatest enemies. As he grows into a young man, Jos is brainwashed into becoming a spy against the human race. At every step, his choices are made for him - until the climatic moment when he takes his life into his own hands.

1. Warchild (2002)
2. Burndive (2003)
3. Cagebird (2005)

http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/l/karin-lowachee/warchild.htm

Comment: I could picture the covers, but couldn't remember the titles, this is what I think it is.

Comment: This is it! Oh my god, you are my hero!